# Calling async method from inside NavigationManager.LocationChanged

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

I am using `NavigationManager.LocationChanged` to capture query strings. After getting the query string value I'm making an ajax call, which is async. LocationChanged itself is synchronous method, and it looks like there is no async version of `LocationChanged`. And when calling async method from inside LocationChanged, the value set by the async method is lagging one step behind.

Here is the repro:

```
@page "/investigate"
@implements IDisposable
@inject NavigationManager NM

<h1>Sync: @SyncValue</h1>
<h1>Async: @AsyncValue</h1>
<button @onclick="TriggerLocationChange">Increment</button>

@code {
    private string SyncValue;
    private string AsyncValue;
    private int Counter = 1;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        NM.LocationChanged += OnLocationChanged;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        NM.LocationChanged -= OnLocationChanged;
    }

    private void OnLocationChanged(object sender, LocationChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        // sync action, just for comparison
        SyncValue = (Counter * 1000).ToString();

        DoSomeAsync();
    }

    private async Task DoSomeAsync()
    {
        // http call to server
        await Task.Delay(1);

        AsyncValue = (Counter * 1000).ToString();
    }

    private void TriggerLocationChange()
    {
        Counter++;
        NM.NavigateTo("investigate?counter=" + Counter);
    }
}
```

The `@AsyncValue` is lagging one step behind from the `@SyncValue`.

How can I prevent the async method from lagging behind when called from inside LocationChanged?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After lots of trial and error, here is what I found:

1. Route parameter values are not yet set when LocationChanged runs. This is not shown in my example above but important in my case. Route parameter can be extracted manually from URL, or we can wait until blazor populates route parameter using `await Task.Delay(1)`.
2. Call `StateHasChanged()` at the end of the async method.
3. [According to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/#invoke-component-methods-externally-to-update-state) we should wrap the call with `base.InvokeAsync(() => ...)`

After these modifications, OnLocationChanged becomes:

```cs
private void OnLocationChanged(object sender, LocationChangedEventArgs args)
{
    // ...

    base.InvokeAsync(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(1);  // wait for blazor to populate route parameters
        await DoSomeAsync();
        StateHasChanged();
    });
}
```

Comment: Your observation re the fields is strange, I think you misinterpreted something. The .ContinuWith() construct is an alternative to async/await but far less commonly used.

Comment: "Don't rely on object fields to have the correct value when the async method runs." This is a false and baseless statement... The use of ContinueWith does not really add any value or solve the issue you're facing. Your code is not working as expected: The first click yields no visual   changes ( except of the query string). On the second click,  SyncValue and AsyncValue display the value 2000, and Counter=2. I've a new answer in which the values of both variables and Counter are the same. No lagging...

Comment: New to Blazor here. Blazor documentation says " A component's lifecycle methods and any event callbacks that are raised by Blazor are executed on the synchronization context." So you shouldn't need to wrap in InvokeAsync right?

Comment: @pholly actually I tried without InvokeAsync and it worked, but please open the link to the official doc that I have provided, it clearly says that we should use InvokeAsync. I have also [asked the same question in github](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/18690).

Comment: OnLocationChanged is an event raised by Blazor so you don't need to use InvokeAsync to get synchronization context. What I quoted is 2 paragraphs above the section you link to. That's why it works without it.

Answer (score 5):

Marking a method with async does not change the signature of the method, hence you should be albe to do this:

```
private async void OnLocationChanged(object sender, LocationChangedEventArgs args)
{
   // sync action:
   SyncValue = (Counter * 1000).ToString();

   await DoSomeAsync();
   StateHasChanged();
}
```

Comment: did you try to make the counter static? ```private int Counter = 1;``` this will always be set to one after each time the page loads.

Comment: Close. You are missing a `StateHasChanged();` after the `await DoSomeAsync();`

Comment: using "async void" is not recommended.